# Animate.css transictions don't repeat it for each element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animate.css

**I'm using Animate css in a React project. I want to repeat the same animation for each render. Now I see only the backgroundColor change, not the animation. (I don't want=> animation-iteration-count: infinite;)
 **

```
<div
  id="left"
  style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.backColor }}
  className={
  "animated slideInUp leftSide d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center "}
>
```

Comment: Please, fill free to add a minimal runable example in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `key={this.props.backColor}` property to `div` to force re-render whole component.

```
<div
  id="left"
  style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.backColor }}
  key={this.props.backColor}
  className={
  "animated slideInUp leftSide d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center "}
>
```

Update: in case you **really** want to re-render component you could use instead `this.props.backColor` for `key` something really new every time, like `Date.now()`, but it's not very efficient, think twice before apply such approach.

```js
function start() {
  const h = React.createElement;

  class Div extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
      return h('div', {
        id: "left",
        key: this.props.backColor,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: this.props.backColor
        },
        className: "animated slideInUp leftSide d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center",
      }, this.props.children)
    }
  }

  function SelectBG(props) {
    return h(
      'div', {}, [
        h('input', {
          key: 'a',
          type: 'button',
          name: 'bg',
          value: 'silver',
          onClick: props.onChange
        }),
        h('input', {
          key: 'b',
          type: 'button',
          name: 'bg',
          value: 'green',
          onClick: props.onChange
        }),
      ]

    );
  }

  function App(props) {
    const [bg, setBG] = React.useState('silver');
    const onChangeBG = React.useCallback((ev) => {
      const bg = ev.target.value;
      setBG(bg);
    }, []);

    return h('section', {}, [
      h(SelectBG, {
        onChange: onChangeBG
      }),
      h(Div, {
        backColor: bg
      }, 'animated div')
    ]);
  }

  ReactDOM.render(h(App), window.app);
}

window.onload = start;
```

```html
<link href="https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="app" />
```

Comment: Good. really thanks. And Is possible to use two animation together ?
Like: when I click your green button the div (with green property) slideOutUp and the silver div slideInUp.

Comment: Why not, but slightly complicated, in thatt case you need set animation dependent on component life cycle. You could use one of library to achieve the same effects, [see related section in react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#can-i-do-animations-in-react)